# Any mechanism to automatically refresh App token in dev.botframework after 60 days

Tags: c#, bots, botframework, facebook-messenger-bot, azure-bot-service

we faced the issue of facebook app secret token expiry after 60 days. We had to manually change the same on dev.botframework to ensure bot is running successfully again. We understand facebook allows programmatically generating new app secret but any way bot framework allows the same to be automatically generated in dev.bot framework facebook messenger channel directly.

Any help is appreciated